# Setting email naming conventions for new user creation via google sheet apps script extension

Tags: google-sheets, new-operator, workspace

I hope the title sums it up well.
Let me preface this question with I am not a developer. I took some basic courses on html & css in college, am tech literate compared to the general population. With that in mind- I am running a startup nonprofit organization that is entirely volunteer based. Myself being the most tech literate of our org... I am trying to automate google workspace new user creation via Google Form entry linked to Sheets.

I've looked at some of your videos on this for python. I have also referenced doing this via Apps Scripts from the following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Fp8bKiQqmc

I don't yet have a specific practice or approach in mind but across what I have watched, I have not read how I can set the naming convention for new user email creation.

I would like new user emails to be first.lastname@domin.org or if it errors out due to already existing starting a counting convention. first.lastname2@domain.org

Do you know is this function possible in the way I describe?

Thank You!
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
=arrayformula(IF(LEN(A4:A),
if(COUNTIFS(A4:A&B4:B, A4:A&B4:B, ROW(A4:A), "<="&ROW(A4:A))=1,
A4:A&B4:B&$B$1,A4:A&B4:B&COUNTIFS(A4:A&B4:B, 
A4:A&B4:B, ROW(A4:A), "<="&ROW(A4:A))&$B$1),))
```

There are many possible solutions for this question.

- One of the attractions of this solution is that it does not require any helper column.
- This is adapted from the answer by [Spencer Farris](https://support.google.com/profile/12305) to [Array Formula: Increment Numbers Within Groups of Rows BUT Reset/Restart the Process as Needed](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/134933967/array-formula-increment-numbers-within-groups-of-rows-but-reset-restart-the-process-as-needed?hl=en) on Google Docs Editors Help.

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: sample]